# Mouse and brightness not working on Ubuntu with Lenovo Ideapad slim 3i

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mouse, lenovo, brightness

My laptop is "Lenovo Ideapad slim 3i". I was trying to install Ubuntu with dual boot Windows 10 with a USB.

When the installation process starts asking: "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu", but my mouse doesn't work. With the help of keyboard I chose try Ubuntu then it opens a Ubuntu interface - here also my mouse doesn't work and screen brightness neither increase nor decrease.

I tried by enabling and disabling secure boot. I face same problem in both the cases.

Also when I try to install (without working mouse) option for normal installation is not there only minimal installation is allowed.

Comment: If your hardware does not work properly in the Try Ubuntu environment, then don't install it. I think you have made it clear enough that your mouse doesn't work; please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1411326/edit) to tell whether your trackpad works or not, and the manufacturer/model of your mouse. Demanding a response ("please reply") is considered rude here

Comment: This also happened to me, it sucked. What fixed it for me I believe was that I was booting in legacy boot mode instead of UEFI mode. It was what the tutorial had suggested but I somehow missed that detail. It seems counterintuitive that you could do a secure boot and the ubuntu usb still boot- you might be on legacy. Another question here might give you some clarity: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216022/dual-booting-ubuntu-12-04-uefi-and-legacy
I think the commenter chalking everything up to a hardware problem is a tad ignorant, though it is rude to say please reply. Everyone on here wants a

Comment: Which Ubuntu version did you try? Please include this in your question.

Comment: @ElleSzabo there is no such thing as "secure boot" in legacy BIOS mode, and Ubuntu can and does work with secure boot.